# High-end system recommendation for vehicle simulations (multi processor vs single processor)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I want to purchase a new computer to run vehicle simulations in Gazebo with simulated sensors (especially velodyne sensors, gps, ..).

I would also like to test different 3D mapping and path planning algorithms in ROS. So there will run like five or more nodes which need a lot of calculation.

For my specific application would it be a better idea to get a multi processor system like a Intel Xeon Silver 4114 (to get a good load balancing on two processors with 10 cores each) or to get the best I9 (9900K) with a very high single core speed?

On both systems I would take a strong GPU (like 2080 RTX TI or a Quadro) and 64 GB RAM.

Thank you guys in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21047/high-end-system-recommendation-for-vehicle-simulations-(multi-processor-vs-single-processor)/) by [ce_guy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7252/ce_guy/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo will consume one core, or two if you're running the GUI. ROS can potentially use many more, and is dependent on what you are running and how you configure ROS.

Gazebo itself will benefit from a high speed core and a good GPU.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2018-11-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pauljurczak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/17996/pauljurczak/) on 2019-11-08**:
Does two core limit still apply to the newest `ign gazebo` version 2.11.0?